# Activate windows authentification in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I'd like to specify the users' profiles how can access to my asp.net mvc application so i put

```
 <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow users="Afif"/>
      <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
```

but the windows authentification didn't work. after googling , i find that i have to activate the windows authentification in `IIS Manager`

[image: active]

But i don't find the windows authentification as in the screenshot.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install IIS, you have to install the Windows Authentication feature.  Go back into the windows components, and change IIS to include the Windows Authentication feature.  See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig/archive/2007/08/20/how-do-i-turn-on-windows-authentication-in-iis-7.aspx) or try this [superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/482428/missing-windows-authentication-feature).

Comment: sorry the link is about iis6 and iis7 but i have another version of iis (8.0) so the two solutions didn't work

Comment: On windows 8?  See this: http://superuser.com/questions/482428/missing-windows-authentication-feature